# JavaFx Combobox value acting wierd

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, fxml

I have been learning javafx and I was trying combobox but cant seem to get output out of combobox properly. When I try to use the value from combobox as String it gives me ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String, and when I try to use the value as an int or an Integer(tried both) it gives me the opposite ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer.

I have tried getting the value using

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

and also with

```
comboBox.getValue();
```

I have tried converting the values explicitly with valueOf, parseInt, and toString. Using getClass also gives a ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer..

This is the combobox I have been using:

```
<ComboBox fx:id="comboBox"  editable="true" promptText="Enter Period in Days"  >
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:id="week" fx:value="7" />
            <String fx:id="fortnite" fx:value="14" />
            <String fx:id="month" fx:value="30" />
            <String fx:id="monthx3" fx:value="90" />
            <String fx:id="year_2" fx:value="180" />
            <String fx:id="year" fx:value="365"/>
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ComboBox>
```

How do I get a value out of this combobox? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Information about getValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#getValue--) [Information about ComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html) The getValue() return a value of the type you've put in it as the options.

Comment: how do I assign the type in fxml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using some type different to `String` and want to keep the `ComboBox` editable, you need to assign a `StringConverter` to the [`ComboBox.converter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#converterProperty) property that is able to convert the `String` to the item type of the `ComboBox`. Otherwise you'll get the `ClassCastException` when the `ComboBox` tries to parse the input of the combobox `TextField`.

Note: Adding an `fx:id` attribute to a element in the fxml does not result in a combination of the `fx:id` and the object created for the element to be used. Instead all it does is allow you to inject the instance to a field in the controller or reference the instance later in the fxml.

Since it seems like you want to keep 2 pieces of information (`String` and `int`) neither `String` nor `Integer` may work for you. You could create a custom type:

```
public class NamedDuration {
    private final int days;
    private final String name;

    public NamedDuration(@NamedArg("days") int days, @NamedArg("name") String name) {
        this.days = days;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

```xml
<ComboBox fx:id="comboBox" editable="true" onAction="#comboChange" promptText="Enter Period in Days">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <NamedDuration name="week" days="7"/>
            <NamedDuration name="fortnite" days="14"/>
            <NamedDuration name="month" days="30"/>
            <NamedDuration name="monthx3" days="90"/>
            <NamedDuration name="year_2" days="180"/>
            <NamedDuration name="year" days="365"/>
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ComboBox>
```

#### Controller class

```
public class FXML2Controller {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<NamedDuration> comboBox;

    @FXML
    private void comboChange() {
        NamedDuration duration = comboBox.getValue();
        if (duration != null) {
            System.out.format("%d days = %s\n", duration.getDays(), duration.getName());
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // set converter to convert between String and NamedDuration
        comboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<NamedDuration>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(NamedDuration object) {
                return object == null ? "" : object.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public NamedDuration fromString(String string) {
                if (string == null || string.isEmpty()) {
                    return null;
                }

                // try matching names
                for (NamedDuration nd : comboBox.getItems()) {
                    if (nd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(string)) {
                        return nd;
                    }
                }

                // try matching number
                int days;
                try {
                    days = Integer.parseInt(string);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    return null;
                }
                for (NamedDuration nd : comboBox.getItems()) {
                    if (days == nd.getDays()) {
                        return nd;
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your FXCollections return String because you declare String inside your collection. If you want integer try this :

```
<ComboBox fx:id="comboBox"  editable="true" promptText="Enter Period in Days"  >
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <Integer fx:id="week" fx:value="7" />
            <Integer fx:id="fortnite" fx:value="14" />
            <Integer fx:id="month" fx:value="30" />
            <Integer fx:id="monthx3" fx:value="90" />
            <Integer fx:id="year_2" fx:value="180" />
            <Integer fx:id="year" fx:value="365"/>
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ComboBox>
```

And 
comboBox.getValue();
Should return Integer.

Comment: My FXCollections doesn't return String when I try to assign it to a string it says cannot assign Integer to String when I tried to cast it to String get a classcastexception. Also tried using Integer as in your example but have the same problem.